# HTML Table with Selection Range using JS JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I tried hard to build the clone of this but failed now I'm here to you.Please make a simple code snippet to help me.[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what precisely you are asking for please?

Comment: @MichaelHurley I need clone of above GIF. i want to have a table with selection criteria. Actually this table is a calendar and I want to select a range of dates in the same way shown in above GIF. Thanks in advance